How to implement DecidableEq on a inductive datatype manually in Lean 4?
I am only a beginner and wanted to know how to manually implement an instance of the Type Class DecidableEq for a simple inductive datatype for the days of the week.
I know you can use deriving to have Lean automatically generate it for me, but I wanted to manually do it to ensure that I understand it myself.
-- Days of the Week
inductive Day : Type where
| monday      : Day
| tuesday     : Day
| wednesday   : Day
| thursday    : Day
| friday      : Day
| saturday    : Day
| sunday      : Day

I could make it work with the follow, but it is very boilerplate code.
open Day

instance : DecidableEq Day :=
fun d₁ d₂ => match d₁, d₂ with
| monday, monday        => isTrue rfl
| tuesday, tuesday      => isTrue rfl
| wednesday, wednesday  => isTrue rfl
| thursday, thursday    => isTrue rfl
| friday, friday        => isTrue rfl
| saturday, saturday    => isTrue rfl
| sunday, sunday        => isTrue rfl

| monday, tuesday       => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| monday, wednesday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| monday, thursday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| monday, friday        => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| monday, saturday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| monday, sunday        => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)

| tuesday, monday       => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| tuesday, wednesday    => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| tuesday, thursday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| tuesday, friday       => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| tuesday, saturday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| tuesday, sunday       => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)

| wednesday, monday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| wednesday, tuesday    => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| wednesday, thursday   => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| wednesday, friday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| wednesday, saturday   => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| wednesday, sunday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)

| thursday, monday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| thursday, tuesday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| thursday, wednesday   => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| thursday, friday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| thursday, saturday    => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| thursday, sunday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)

| friday, monday        => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| friday, tuesday       => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| friday, wednesday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| friday, thursday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| friday, saturday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| friday, sunday        => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)

| saturday, monday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| saturday, tuesday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| saturday, wednesday   => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| saturday, thursday    => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| saturday, friday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| saturday, sunday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)

| sunday, monday        => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| sunday, tuesday       => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| sunday, wednesday     => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| sunday, thursday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| sunday, friday        => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)
| sunday, saturday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)

ideally, I want to use underscores for the none equal cases such as:
open Day

instance : DecidableEq Day :=
fun d₁ d₂ => match d₁, d₂ with
| monday, monday        => isTrue rfl
| tuesday, tuesday      => isTrue rfl
| wednesday, wednesday  => isTrue rfl
| thursday, thursday    => isTrue rfl
| friday, friday        => isTrue rfl
| saturday, saturday    => isTrue rfl
| sunday, sunday        => isTrue rfl
| _,_                   => isFalse (by sorry)

I've tried induction but it includes all cases even those that are equal as above. Any suggest will be greatly appreciated.

The problem is that, when you use a wildcard in a pattern match, Lean will "forget" about which branch you're in, so, once you've done that, there is no way to recover the lost information.
However, we can still cut much of the verbosity by using tactics.  Tactics are generally thought of as something only useful for proving stuff, but actually, they're general purpose metaprogramming facilities, and can be used to code even "normal" programs.  For instance, the instance can be written as follows:
instance : DecidableEq Day := by
  intros d₁ d₂
  cases d₁ <;> cases d₂ <;> first
    | right; rfl
    | left; intro; contradiction

This does pattern matching on d₁ and d₂, like your original code does, and then for each branch, tries to construct the decidable instance with whichever of isTrue or isFalse makes the code typecheck.
This has been written entirely in "proof-style", but, depending on your use case, and on your personal preference, you can mix to various degrees both styles, ie.
instance : DecidableEq Day := fun d₁ d₂ => by
  cases d₁ <;> cases d₂ <;> first
    | exact isTrue rfl
    | exact isFalse <| by
        intro h
        contradiction

Also, here are some additional tips if you want to make your code less verbose, in general:
If you are writing a function for which you immediately want to pattern match on the arguments, you can avoid naming these arguments:
rather than
fun d₁ d₂ => match d₁, d₂ with
  | monday, monday        => isTrue rfl
  | ...

you can have
fun
  | monday, monday => isTrue rfl
  | ...

Furthermore, if several branches of a pattern match have the same code, you can factor them:
fun
  | monday, monday      
  | tuesday, tuesday    
  | wednesday, wednesday
  | thursday, thursday  
  | friday, friday      
  | saturday, saturday  
  | sunday, sunday        => isTrue rfl

  | monday, tuesday       
  | monday, wednesday     
  | monday, thursday      
  | monday, friday        
  | monday, saturday      
  | monday, sunday        

  | tuesday, monday       
  | tuesday, wednesday    
  | tuesday, thursday     
  | tuesday, friday       
  | tuesday, saturday     
  | tuesday, sunday       

  | wednesday, monday     
  | wednesday, tuesday    
  | wednesday, thursday   
  | wednesday, friday     
  | wednesday, saturday   
  | wednesday, sunday     

  | thursday, monday      
  | thursday, tuesday     
  | thursday, wednesday   
  | thursday, friday      
  | thursday, saturday    
  | thursday, sunday      

  | friday, monday        
  | friday, tuesday       
  | friday, wednesday     
  | friday, thursday      
  | friday, saturday      
  | friday, sunday        

  | saturday, monday      
  | saturday, tuesday     
  | saturday, wednesday   
  | saturday, thursday    
  | saturday, friday      
  | saturday, sunday      

  | sunday, monday        
  | sunday, tuesday       
  | sunday, wednesday     
  | sunday, thursday      
  | sunday, friday        
  | sunday, saturday      => isFalse (by intro h; contradiction)

In this case, it doesn't make things sufficiently better, but in other cases, this could be enough.

Thank you. The example with "right" didn't work for me. I think I need to import something for that tactic. But your other example worked perfectly. Follow up question: You mentioned it doesn't remember which path you take. Is there a way to remember stuff before going down that path. I know Coq has a Remember tactic. Could something like that be used here?

@casillic Lean has mechanisms that do the same thing as Remember in Coq (try to replace match x with with match h : x with), but this still wouldn't work. The issue is that there are several cases (ie. d₁ = monday, or d₁ = tuesday, or ...) which are turned into a single case, so d₁ cannot be "substituted by its value" as it would in single-cases branch. I hope this is clear.  As for right, try swapping left and right in my examples to see if it works for you. Otherwise, you can do apply isTrue and apply isFalse instead.
